# How to call RDF report in oracle PL/SQL Procedure?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apps

I want to call RDF report inside the oracle pl/sql procedure with dynamic  parameter.And send that report output to email. I am using oracle EBS 12.1.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the reports are on the same server as the database, you can set up a DBMS_SCHEDULER job that runs a shell script that calls `rwrun`, and invoke this in your PLSQL.

The `rwrun` command has options to send the result via email:

```
rwrun report=myrep.rdf userid=un/pw@db desformat=pdf DESTYPE=mail DESNAME="u1@myc.com, u2@myco.com" cc="u3@myco.com" bcc="u4@myco.com" replyto="me@myco.com" from="me@mycop.com"
```

Other options are to use `UTL_HTTP` or similar to issue a `rwcgi` request to run the report.

See here for available options for running a Report:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/bi.1012/b14048/pbr_cla.htm#i634293

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97329_03/bi.902/a92102/pbr_cla.htm#634395

**Edited to show how to create via DBMS_SCHEDULER.**

DBMS_SCHEDULER is a highly flexible and configurable feature with Oracle, with lots of options and often a offering a few ways to do things so the following is a generic example to get you started.

First create a shell script which runs the report:

run_rdf.sh:

```
rwrun report=myrep.rdf ...
```

Now script to create the DBMS_SCHEDULER job:

```
BEGIN
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_PROGRAM (
      program_name=> 'RUN_RDF',
      program_type=> 'EXECUTABLE',
      program_action  => '/bin/bash run_rdf.sh',
      enabled=> TRUE,
      comments=> 'Run RDF report'
   );
END;
/
```

You can add arguments to this program that would then get passed to the script:

```
BEGIN
 DBMS_SCHEDULER.DEFINE_PROGRAM_ARGUMENT (
   program_name            => 'RUN_RDF',
   argument_position       => 1,
   argument_name           => 'arg_name',
   argument_type           => 'VARCHAR2',
   default_value           => '');
END;
/
```

So you must decide whether the parameters/arguments will be hardcoded into teh shell script, as passed in directly as command line args when defining `program_action` above, or set dynamically via the `DEFINE_PROGRAM_ARGUMENT`  feature (see what I mean about there being several ways to use this?).

Set this as a runable job but do not specify times:

```
BEGIN
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
      job_name     => 'RUN_RDF_JOB',
      program_name => 'RUN_RDF',
      start_date => NULL,
      repeat_interval => NULL,
      end_date => NULL,
      enabled => FALSE,
      auto_drop => FALSE,
      comments => '');
END;
/
```

To run:

```
BEGIN
   -- Set arguments values
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_job_argument_value('RUN_RDF_JOB',1,'arg1 value');
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE_JOB('RUN_RDF_JOB'); -- Might need this
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB('RUN_RDF_JOB');
END;
/
```

Monitor the job via the views (ALL/USER/DBA as necessary):

```
ALL_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS
ALL_SCHEDULER_JOB_LOG
```

Comment: Could  you please provide me the  sample code that how can i schedule my rdf report using dbms_schedular?and to send that output in pdf format through  email?@TenG

Comment: Actually, the answer above showing how to do this using EBS Concurrent Programs is better since that is what the Conc Programs facility is designed for.

Comment: I have already tried the Conc Program method but its no helpful for me.Actually I have a requirement that I have to send daily attendance of  subordinates to its line manager.And there are 40+ managers so its no a good choice to create 40+ Conc Program and schedule them simultaneously.I want to create to create procedure which call the RDF report which is placed on the server and pass manager code as input parameter using loop and send that report output to the managers using email.

Comment: @Farooq I have added a generic example of how you might use DBMS_SCHEDULER. I think this is enough to get you started.